# Connect to Azure SQL in Python with MFA Active Directory Interactive Authentication without using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory dll

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, multi-factor-authentication

To connect to Azure SQL Database using MFA (which is in SSMS as "Active Directory - Universal") Microsoft recommends and currently only has a tutorial on connecting with C# using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Setting `Authentication='Active Directory Interactive';` in a regular ODBC connection string from Python or Powershell results in the error

```
Cannot find an authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
```

This seems to be because per Microsoft's example code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db you need to explicitly create your own auth provider class when creating  the connection:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var provider = new ActiveDirectoryAuthProvider();

            SC.SqlAuthenticationProvider.SetProvider(
                SC.SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryInteractive,
                //SC.SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryIntegrated,  // Alternatives.
                //SC.SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryPassword,
                provider);

            Program.Connection();
        }
```

I want to connect with pyodbc, so I can't implement the ActiveDirectoryInteractive provider.

Is there any way to generically acquire a token using OAuth and use it in the connection string, or otherwise implement the ActiveDirectoryInteractive provider without using .NET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15) support the MFA authentication, but windows only:
[image]

I tested in Python pyodbc and it also works.

Here is my `pyodbc` code which connect to my Azure SQL database with AAD MFA authentication:

```
import pyodbc
server = '***.database.windows.net'
database = 'Mydatabase'
username ='****@****.com'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';SERVER='+server+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication
                      )

print(conn)
```

It works well in my windows environment.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Depending on your setup you might not need to provide the password in your connection string. If I do, I get the following error: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Password option must not be specified, if Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'. You simply insert the password intot he Windows pop-up.

Answer (score 28):

### Authenticating using AAD MFA from MacOS / Linux

I was facing the same problem but on MacOs. As described above, the ODBC option using '*ActiveDirectoryInteractive*' is only available for Windows.

If you want to see a more detailed version of this post, please check out my post on [Medium](https://medium.com/@everton_b.o/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-with-mfa-using-python-on-macos-linux-de11cfdefb63), otherwise keep reading. ;)

### Requirements

In order to connect to the database using AAD MFA, I also used `pyodbc` but with an access token. To get the token there are a few things that you'll need to do:

1. [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)
2. [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server (Linux-MAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

### Instructions

Before you run the code below, you must authenticate using azure cli, to do so run from cmd : `az login`

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
import struct
import pyodbc 

# input params
server = '<your server address>'
database = '<database name>'
query = 'SELECT * from dbo.Address;'

# Use the cli credential to get a token after the user has signed in via the Azure CLI 'az login' command.
credential = AzureCliCredential()
databaseToken = credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/')

# get bytes from token obtained
tokenb = bytes(databaseToken[0], "UTF-8")
exptoken = b'';
for i in tokenb:
 exptoken += bytes({i});
 exptoken += bytes(1);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;

# build connection string using acquired token
connString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+""
SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256 
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before = {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct});

# sample query
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

### Troubleshooting

Some people might experience different behavior using the code above depending on the version of the ODBC driver and MacOS.

1. Make sure to always use the latest version of the ODBC driver
2. If your connection returns an error similar to 'SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate] (-1)'. Adding `TrustServerCertificate=Yes;` to the connection string can help.

**References**

https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database

Comment: This is the only method I found on the whole Stackoverflow that actually works. Thank you.

Comment: You are a true hero! However, I had to add .default to the URL https://database.windows.net/ so it becomes https://database.windows.net/.default

Comment: Everton, your reply solved a problem that I'd been working on for two years! Thank you so much!

Comment: A rare case of something that just works after you copy and paste it directly into your editor. Hats off to Mr. Barciela!

Comment: This is excellent. Solves the problem I've been having with db connections in Docker perfectly. Thank you Everton.

Comment: Note for anyone using pandas, to avoid warnings re sqlalchemy, you can use urllib and sqlalchemy to create the engine with `params = urllib.parse.quote(connString)`
`engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={0}".format(params), connect_args={'attrs_before': {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct}})`

Comment: You Sir, are an absolute wizard! Thank you for the code as well as the clear, concise explanation.

Comment: I am getting the following error. Any suggestions? `pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: @tiagoams, are you able to connect to this instance via azure data studio? If so, are you using Mac M2 Chip?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Everton, but I think the problem I am having is that I need to install "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" in windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode directly in `UTF-16 LE`, you don't need to use a loop as you did in your example.

Therefore, this will work too.

```
# get bytes from token obtained
tokenb = bytes(databaseToken[0], "UTF-16-LE")
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(tokenb)) + tokenb;
```