# How to enable "remember me" with Sql Authentication Method ActiveDirectoryInteractive?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

**Use case**: A native(.NET desktop) app that connects to Azure SQL Database using Azure Active Directory authentication.

Since .NET 4.7.2 there is new `SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryInteractive` setting for opening a connection to DB. This setting results in a pop-up dialog for sign in, which works well.
E.g. [Some documentation example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db)

**Problem**: Each time the desktop app is restarted - the sign-in popup appears again, asking for password again, which is frustrating for people who prefer "remember me on this PC" kind of behavior.

Is there a way to enable "remember me" in this scenario ? I didn't find anything in the documentation / web / SO ...

P.S. I assume I can implement it myself if I work with JWT tokens and not with `ActiveDirectoryInteractive`, but before I do that asking here.

Comment: Yes, there is a new authentication enum value: `SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryInteractive` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db#new-authentication-enum-value) that is designed for user access. You should be using `SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` if the user is on a Windows domain that is federated with Azure AD and individual user account access is required. If individual user accounts are not required, then there are additional options that can be shared.

Comment: Thanks @MikeUbezziMSFT, "Integrated" is indeed for a bit different scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a `Token Cache` option from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60566500/9215033).

Which eventually helps with the problem of sign-in popup upon each restart, due to caching the token.
Get the `FilesBasedAdalV3TokenCache` class and then provide it when initializing `AuthenticationContext`:

```
...
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(parameters.Authority, new FilesBasedAdalV3TokenCache(".\\Token.dat"));
...
```