# How to connect C# unittest with Azure Synapse SSDT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, sql-server-data-tools, azure-synapse

I already created the DB project and was able to deploy the scripts using the `dacpac` file. I'd like to write `unittest` for this Synapse DB. I created a `unittest` project choosing `C#` and was able to create a test and ran it successfully with this connection string in `app.config`:

`ConnectionString="Data Source={mydevdbenvname}.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog={mydbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={myemail@address};Password={password};Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=&quot;Active Directory Password&quot;"`

My problem is when I'm trying to connect to the DB using `Active Directory Interactive`:

`ConnectionString="Data Source={mydevdbenvname}.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog={mydbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={myemail@address};Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=&quot;Active Directory Interactive&quot;"`

Getting the following error:

> Message:
> Initialization method Synapse_unittest.SqlServerUnitTest.TestInitialize threw
> exception. System.ArgumentException: System.ArgumentException: Cannot
> find an authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'..

It seems I have to create an app in Azure portal and grant permissions there. I'm following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db) but I don't know how to pass the `appID` in the `app.config` file or where to put the `C#` code to override the class that is connecting to the DB.

[image]

I'm not a `C#` dev. Please any help or clue will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your DB connection string should be like below.

```
Data Source=sqlserver.database.windows.net;User ID=user@domain.com;Initial Catalog=database;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive
```

And you also need to configure something on portal. Thanks for [Alberto Morillo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564462/how-to-connect-to-a-database-using-active-directory-login-and-multifactor-authen), in his answer, there are specific configurations and detailed codes.

Comment: He just copied and pasted the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db) that I'm already following. I already did all of it and same result.