# Azure SQL Active Directory interactive authentication from SSIS package

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am trying to execute my SSIS package from Azure enables SSIS project in VS 2019. SSIS package needs to connect with Azure SQL database using Active Directory Interactive authentication.

Test connection succeeded with the connection string provided and I am also able to parse the query in Execute SQL task.

But when the package is run, the task fails with an error

> Failed to acquire connection

I am not able to connect via Script task also. It fails with an error

> DTS.Runtime - Cannot find an authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'

Has anyone succeeded connecting to Azure SQL from SSIS & SQL Server Agent job. Is SQL Server authentication the only way?

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to acquire connection | DTS.Runtime - Cannot find an
> authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'

**ActiveDirectoryInteractive** (i.e, `authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive`) can be used to connect to an ***Azure SQL Database***/ Synapse Analytics using an interactive authentication flow (***multi-factor authentication***) which uses **`System.Data.SqlClient`**

It will fail because **MFA** interactive is ***not*** supported by **`SqlClient`** provider.

Please note that the **`System.Data.SqlClient`** driver does not support the full range of Azure AD authentication methods. If none of the supported methods works in your environment, using **SQL authentication** may be the only option.

Ensure that you have at least the **`.NET Framework 4.7.2 version`**.

Or Try with **ODBC driver connection**.

Check this thread, [c# - How to connect to a database using Active directory Login and MultiFactor Authentication (MFA) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564462/how-to-connect-to-a-database-using-active-directory-login-and-multifactor-authen/60566040#60566040)

For more details, [ActiveDirectoryInteractive connects to SQL - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db)

Raise a **support request** if issue still remains.